# RestController: returning Resource<> makes FetchType.LAZY to behave as FetchType.EAGER

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am having below mappings as `Company` having `1:N` relation with `CompanyFunds`

```
@Entity
public class Company{

    @Id
    private Integer companyId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<CompanyFund> companyFunds;

}

@Entity
public class CompanyFunds{

    @Id
    private Integer fundId;

    private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
  private Company company;

}
```

I am using `Spring-data-Jpa` for my persistence layer and below are the controller and service methods:

```
//controller
@GetMapping(value = "/{companyId}")
public Resource<Company> find(@PathVariable Integer companyId) {

  Resource<Company> companyResource = companyService.find(companyId);
  return companyResource;
}

//service
public Resource<CompanyTypeOther> find(Integer companyId) {
  Company company =  companyRepository.findById(companyId);

  return restResourceAssembler.toResource(company);
}


@Component
public class RestResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<T, Resource<T>> {

    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    public RestResourceAssembler(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public  Resource<T>  toResource(T entity) {
        Resource<T> resource = new Resource<>(entity);
        resource.add(entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(entity.getClass(), entity.getId()).withSelfRel());

        return resource;
    }
}
```

Now the weird thing is, until the `return companyResource;`(in controller) doesn't get executed, the `companyResource` contains `null` for `companyFunds` i.e the LAZY loading is working fine till that point. But the moment the `return companyResource;` executes, something goes inside the Spring and the `Select` statement for `CompanyFund` gets fired. I debugged the steps and below is the code(`try` block) responsible for this:

```
public class ServletInvocableHandlerMethod extends InvocableHandlerMethod {

  ......

  public void invokeAndHandle(ServletWebRequest webRequest, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
    ........other code
    try {
      this.returnValueHandlers.handleReturnValue(
          returnValue, getReturnValueType(returnValue), mavContainer, webRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
        logger.trace(formatErrorForReturnValue(returnValue), ex);
      }
      throw ex;
    }
  }

  .....

}
```

There are no `toString()` declared in entities, also no `getCompanyFund()` called. Can't understand what Spring is doing with `returnValue` above, so that some getters(or something) are getting called.

One more thing I noticed is, this problem only occurs when the `Resource<Company>` is returned. If I return `Company` from the controller, nothing unexpected happens. Lazy loading works fine.

Comment: does the JSON response (Company) include links/references to related entities (CompanyFunds) ? your issue could be related to Spring HATEOS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989857/jackson-triggering-jpa-lazy-fetching-on-serialization

Comment: No, it's only creating a self link.

Answer (score 0):

Since I want to lazy load the entity, a little fix/hack solved the problem for me(as of now).

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
private List<CompanyFund> companyFunds;
```

`@JsonIgnore` prevents LAZY loaded entity from being serialized. So I guess the jackson is the culprit here.

**This is not a fix is my view but just a hack to do the thing**. Still waiting someone from `Spring` team to reply.

Comment: Lazy doesnt mean dont return it, lazy means dont do join to eagerly fetch, but when you return it in jackson land, you are navigating all properties by default, not sure why the surprise! Typically you ll have a view layer that calls service and returns elements that client needs, and not expose database structure, in case you want to change it

Comment: By view layer, you mean adding DTOs?

Comment: Yes I meant dto

Comment: But adding unnecessary DTOs would add extra serialization deserialization affecting the response time, though with a very small margin for most of the applications.

Comment: Entity to DTO is not called serialization, its in memory mapping, hardly an issue. All serious applications that I have ever coded have always done it